# Overcoming slow button and frame display and patchy backgrounds for a custom ButtonFrame during frame resizing.

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written an algorithm that allows a `ttk.Frame` to wrap multiple buttons within it such that when the buttons take up too much space horizontally the affected buttons will automatically be relocated to a subsequent row. Such button wrapping behaviour will also be exhibited when this ttk.Frame resizes. I have called this a `FrameButton` class.

This widget has issues still:

1. It's button wrapping behavior and the resizing of the frame is very laggy/delayed. Faster response is needed.
2. During resizing, the background color of the frame shows the master widget's background whenever the buttons are removed to facilitate re-position.
3. During repositioning, when a row of buttons exceed the frame width, I had to remove the last button on the row to reposition it the a new row. This procedure causes a grey out effect on the right side of the frame.
4. When I am resizing the height of the frame, the buttons position should not be affected but presently because of the  binding used the buttons would still reposition itself to the same position. Such a wrapping behavior is redundant and I would like to avoid it.

How can I circumvent/overcome the above mentioned issues? Thank you.

**FrameButtons.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6.5
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Load python3 modules
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import platform

class FrameButtons(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, **options):
        background  = master.winfo_toplevel().cget('background') 
        style       = options.pop( 'style', ttk.Style() )
        background  = options.pop( 'background', background )
        borderwidth = options.pop( 'borderwidth', 0 )
        relief      = options.pop( 'relief', 'flat' )
        texts       = options.pop( 'texts', ['0'] )
        textwidth   = options.pop( 'textwidth', 10 )
        debug       = options.pop( 'debug', False )

        master.update_idletasks()
        masterwidth = master.winfo_width()
        masterwidth2 = masterwidth - borderwidth*2
        print('masterwidth, w/border = ', masterwidth, masterwidth2)
        width =  masterwidth2

        super().__init__( master, style='main.TFrame', width=width,
                          borderwidth=borderwidth, relief=relief )
        self.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew' )

        master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.parent = master
        self.style = style
        self.texts = texts
        self.bg = None
        self.background = background
        self.borderwidth = borderwidth
        self.relief = relief
        self.textwidth = textwidth
        self.debug = debug
        self.buttonframes = {}
        self.buttons = {}

        #Color code borders
        if self.debug:
            if platform.system() == 'Linux':
                print('Linux')
                bg = []
                with open('/etc/X11/rgb.txt') as f:
                    lines = f.readlines()[30::10]
                    for line in lines:
                        color = line.replace('\t\t',' ').splitlines()[0]\
                                .split()[3]
                        #print('color = ', color)
                        invalid = ['ghost','floral','old','antique','papaya',
                                  'blanched','peach','navajo','lemon','alice',
                                  'cornflower','slate','light','royal', 'dark',
                                  'mint','misty','dim','midnight','medium','dodger',
                                  'deep','sky','steel','pale','rosy','indian',
                                   'saddle','sandy','DebianRed', 'spring','forest',
                                   'sea','lawn','cadet']
                        if color not in invalid:
                            bg.append( color )
                self.bg = bg
            else:
                print('non-Linux')
                self.bg = [ 'yellow', 'red','blue', 'grey','cyan','orange',
                            'black','gold','magenta','silver','maroon', 'salmon',
                            'honeydew','hotpink','indigo','ivory','khaki',
                            'lavender', 'lawn green', 'light blue','lime',
                            'midnight blue', 'olive']
        else:
            #no debug
            self.bg = [ str(x).replace( str(x), background )
                        for x in range( len(texts) ) ]
        print(self.bg)

        self._setStyle()
        self._createWidgets()
        self._setBindings()


    def _setStyle( self ):
        self.style.configure( 'main.TFrame', background=self.background, 
                                             borderwidth=self.borderwidth,
                                             relief=self.relief )
        self.style.configure( 'buttons.TFrame', background=self.background )
        self.style.configure( 'b.TButton', justify=tk.CENTER,
                                           width=self.textwidth ) 


    def _createButtonFrame( self, r ):
        self.buttonframes[r] = tk.Frame( self, background=self.bg[r],
                                               borderwidth=self.borderwidth,
                                               relief=self.relief )
        self.buttonframes[r].pack( anchor='w' )


    def _createButton( self, r, b):
        self.buttons[b] = ttk.Button( self, text=b, style='b.TButton' )
        self.buttons[b].pack( in_=self.buttonframes[r], anchor='w', side='left')
        self.buttons[b].update_idletasks()

    def _updateButtonFrame( self, r):
        return self.buttonframes[r].winfo_reqwidth()


    def _createWidgets( self ):
        wlimit = self.cget('width')
        print('wlimit = ', wlimit)
        self._createWidgets2( wlimit)


    def _createWidgets2( self, wlimit ):
        t_width=0; r=0; i=0 
        self._createButtonFrame( r )
        r +=1

        for b in self.texts:

            if t_width <= wlimit:
                self._createButton( r-1, b )
                i += 1

                t_width = self._updateButtonFrame( r-1 )
                if self.debug: print( 'r={}, i={}, t_width={}'
                                      .format( r-1, i-1, t_width ) )

                # if buttons row width exceeded wlimit
                if t_width > wlimit:
                    if self.debug: print('t_width > wlimit ({})'.format(wlimit) )
                    #remove button
                    self.buttons[b].pack_forget()
                    i -= 1

                    self._createButtonFrame( r )
                    r += 1
                    # create button
                    self._createButton(r-1, b)
                    i += 1
                    # update t_width
                    t_width = self._updateButtonFrame( r-1 )
                    if self.debug: print( 'r={}, i={}, t_width={}'
                                          .format( r-1, i-1, t_width ) )


    def _setBindings(self):
        self.bind( '<Configure>', self._configButtonFrame )


    def _configButtonFrame (self, event):
        self.parent.update_idletasks()
        wlimit = self.parent.winfo_width() - self.borderwidth*2
        #print('wlimit = ', wlimit)

        #remove old ButtonFrame widgets
        self._cleanup()
        self._createWidgets2( wlimit )


    def _cleanup(self):
        for k in self.buttons.keys():
            self.buttons[k].destroy()
        self.buttons.clear()
        for k in self.buttonframes.keys():
            self.buttonframes[k].destroy()
        self.buttonframes.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry( '102x500+10+0' )
    borderwidth = 10
    width = 100
    minwidth = width+borderwidth*2; print('minwidth =', minwidth)
    root.minsize( minwidth, 300)

    texts = [ str(x) for x in range(20) ]

    app = FrameButtons( root, background='pink', borderwidth=borderwidth,
                        relief=tk.RAISED, texts=texts, textwidth=2,
                        debug=True )
    root.mainloop() # Start Dynamic part of program to handle Tk events
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you can do is stop creating new widgets on every `<Configure>` event. Create them once, then move them only when you've computed that they need to move. When I resize the main window just wide enough to create a single row, your code will have created anywhere from 200 to 2000 buttons or more depending on how fast I do the resize.

### An alternate solution

You might want to consider using `grid` rather than `pack`, since `grid` doesn't require that you create internal frames for each row.

Here's a quick and dirty example to illustrate the concept. It hasn't been tested much, but it seems to work:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class FrameButtons(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.buttons = []
        self.bind("<Configure>", self._redraw)

    def _redraw(self, event=None):
        maxwidth = self.winfo_width()
        row = column = rowwidth = 0
        for button in self.buttons:
            # will it fit? If not, move to the next row
            if rowwidth + button.winfo_width() > maxwidth:
                row += 1
                column = 0
                rowwidth = 0
            rowwidth += button.winfo_width()
            button.grid(row=row, column=column)
            column += 1

    def add_button(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''Add one button to the frame'''
        button = ttk.Button(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.buttons.append(button)
        self._redraw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    button_frame = FrameButtons(root)
    button_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
    for i in range(20):
        button_frame.add_button(text=str(i))
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Bryan. :) `Grid` method is surely most appropriate for this case. I have learnt much. I have changed `maxwidth = self.winfo_width() - self.borderwidth*2` so that buttons only appear within frame and its border (right side). When reducing Window height to less than the total height of the buttons, the button will overlap the frame border. The same phenomenon appears on right side also when window width is less than 1 button width. How can these overlap appearances be avoided?