# How to allow continuous switching of focus in a group of tkinter widgets w/o getting stuck at the last widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have several tkinter `Entry` and `Combobox` widgets that I can use the `Tab` key to change focus from one widget to another. However, when the focus arrives at the last widget, the focus remains at the last widget and does not continue back to the first widget when `Tab` is pressed. How can i get this continuation in the switching of focus?

Comment: I cannot duplicate that. When I create 10 entries and tab through them, when I'm on the last widget and press tab it cycles back to the first as I would expect. Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have been trying to develop the MCV example to replicate issue but could not either. Arrived at the same finding as you. I will continue to work from the MCV to debug this issue and keep you posted. From your experience, any clues on possible factors causing such an issue? Cheers.

Comment: @BryanOakley I finally found the cause. :) Prior to creating the `Entry` widgets, I had created 20 [FrameButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52393141/5722359) that you had previously adviced me on. I discovered that I needed 21 presses of the `Tab` button before the `Entry` widget would get selected again. I will look to altering the `FrameButton` customised style to force it's appearance during `Tab` keypress. So far, I had tried defining the `Framebuttons` with `takefocus=False` to remove the effect of the `Tab` keypress and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the reasons to my issue:

1. I had created several
   [FrameButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52393141/5722359) widgets
   before creating the Entry widgets and Combobox widget. By default,
   these FrameButtons had `takefocus=True` option defined.
2. These `Framebuttons`, being a `ttk` type widget, were created using a
   custom style layout such that it *only* had `padding` and `label` elements. That is, it did not have a `focus` element.

Hence when the `Tab` key was pressed after the Combobox widget, focus had indeed move to the Framebutons. But because these `FrameButtons` did not consist a focus element, the focus on these buttons could not be seen. And because there were many such buttons and the Combobox fieldbackground was selected after focus had left it, the effects of pressing the `Tab` key felt as it focus had stopped at the Combobox. To visualise `focus` in the `FrameButtons`, I only had to ensure these button widgets had a `focus` layout element like so:

```
    buttonlayout =[('Button.focus', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
                    [('Button.padding', {'sticky':'nswe', 'children':
                      [('Button.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]})]
    s.layout('my.TButton', buttonlayout)
```

Summary:

1. By default, `Tab` keypress will cycle through all widgets defined
   with option `takefocus=True` in the order in which they are created.
2. If focus appears to stop at a certain widget, do ensure the
   ttk widgets in your tkinter GUI has the focus element defined in its 
   style layout. Else these widgets will not show they have focus.